# Formula not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

*Using following Data my Formula does't gets correct Answer.*

[image]

- The Task is, `Sum` all Cells has Text starts with `P`.
- Using this Formula:

  ```
  =SUM(IF(MID(A1:A4,3,1)="P",--SUBSTITUTE(A1:A4,MID(A1:A4,3,99),"")))
  ```
- Expected result is `20`.

**Note:**

- I'm in need of single Formula, no Split
  & Helper sort of solution is required.
- This 
  `=SUBSTITUTE(A3,MID(A3,3,99),"")`returns
  `12`, means the parameter I'm using 
  with formula is correct.

Comment: Your formula is only looking at the 3rd letter. It is the 4th letter in `12 Pcs`

Comment: @DavidPostill, thanks for observation, could U suggest how to make a common Formula to access all Ps, I've already tried `If (or(MID,,,` but not working !

Comment: No. I'm not an excel user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(A1:A4,FIND(" ",A1:A4)+1,1)="P")*(LEFT(A1:A4,FIND(" ",A1:A4)-1)))
```

[image]

The first factor in `SUMPRODUCT()` grabs the first-character-after-space and compares it to **P**.  The second factor in `SUMPRODUCT()` grabs the number-before-space.

Comment: Thanks @Gary's Student ,, now it's working. Could you fix this one I've used giving `25`.   `{=SUM(IF(OR(MID(A1:A4,4,1)="P",MID(A1:A4,3,1)="P"),--SUBSTITUTE(A1:A4,MID(A1:A4,3,99),"")))`

Answer (score 0):

**This Array (CSE) Formula can be used also:**

[image]

```
{=SUM(IF(MID(A1:A4,3,1)="P",(--SUBSTITUTE(A1:A4,MID(A1:A4,3,99),""))))+SUM(IF(MID(A1:A4,4,1)="P",(--SUBSTITUTE(A1:A4,MID(A1:A4,4,99),""))))}
```

**N.B.**

- Finish Formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.